Issue with registering assembly with reference to microsoft.office.uc.dll
Trying to implement IM like in link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/integrating-im-applications-with-office.
The problem is, when I try to register assembly with dscom I get follow error: Failed to export type library. Failed to set GUID for AsynchronousOperation. Duplicate ID in inheritance hierarchy. (0x800288C6 (TYPE_E_DUPLICATEID))
I assume, that library already registered as COM. So question is, which name of this COM, so I can reuse it in my project.
I linked assembly directly in project and get described issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
